# Django resetting database value to 0 every month?

Tags: mysql, django, database

My app has the user upload documents. I'd like to easily be able to the tell the user how records they've uploaded in the past year and month.

I understand how to do queries on the database where I can do one-time calculations by user: example for year

```
 MyDocs.objects.filter(created_at__year=year, user__username=name)
```

However I'm trying to figure out if this is the most efficient path if I have to return these values often for many users and am considering adding more columns in my CustomUser model (my model that extends my user model) so that it's very easy to return one value.

Example:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_uploads = models.IntegerField()
    year_uploads = models.IntegerField()
    month_uploads = models.IntegerField()
```

Obviously, this would be very easy to do if I just needed to record total_uploads. The problem would be when on the first of the month I need to set the month_uploads to 0 for every account.

I know that there are ways you can set scheduled database updates to set fields to 0 on a timed basis.

My question is: is there an easy way to build in month resets to 0 into a Django model? Or is there another strategy that apps use to count without having to query the entire database to count each time.

Comment: What's our problem exactly ? models.IntField() => models.IntegerField().

Why this will be problem to set 0 as a total_uploads value on the first day of the month ?

Comment: Just make one update query once in a month.

Comment: @gachdavit (edited IntField -> IntegerField, just typed it up for demo and didn't realize it was wrong). Yeah, I am trying to figure out what is the typical strategy that people employ here. It's becoming more clear to me that the idea is to update fields every month / year.

Comment: @gachdavit so probably a better question that I should have asked would have been whats the strategy for scheduled updates to tables. Django model feature / cron job / celary

Comment: You want to run one script (for example SQL query in N days). Cron job is ideal for this kind of tasks. Call "Django Commands" from Cron or write little python script. Good luck.